# Master.FindControl ( HiddenField) Common Method

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Was looking to find a common method to get all hidden field values from master page

The fields are added in master page and the hidden field values has to be get from masterpage , based on the client page requests

Any good / better way to implement this with code samples ? Thanks in advance

- Joe

Answer (score 1):

Not clear on where you would need this, or how you need the data, however from your master page code behind you could:

```
var values = (from HiddenField hidden in Controls select hidden.Value)
  .ToList();
```

This will populate values from the `Value` property from all your `HiddenField`s

Update:

Off your master page just expose some properties:

```
public partial class MyMasterPage : MasterPage
{
    public string Hidden1Value
    {
        get
        { return Hidden1.Value; }
        set
        { Hidden1.Value = value; }
     }

    public string Hidden2Value
    {
        get
        { return Hidden2.Value; }
        set
        { Hidden2.Value = value; }
     }
}
```

Then in your page code behind:

```
var master = (MyMasterPage) Page.Master;
master.Hidden1Value = "something";
```

In your CommonMethods class reference these hidden values like so:

```
public class CommonMethods
{
    public static void SomeMethod(MyMasterPage master)
    {
        master.Hidden1Value = "something";
    }
}
```

And then a call from your aspx Page for example:

```
CommonMethods.SomeMethod((MyMasterPage) Master);
```

Side Note: I would highly recommend changing your architecture to not do this. Passing MasterPage instances around your code is not really recommended.

Comment: I want to get rid off the session used , instead of that I want to use hidden field                    if (!(Context.Items.Contains("Roles")))
                    {
                        Context.Items.Add("Roles", sRoleName);
                                  Session["Roles"] = Context.Items["Roles"].ToString();                   
                    }    ,                                                                                          I need a common method to be added in master , so that all the hidden fields from the client aspx will be able to generate the hiddenfield values

Comment: @Joe added some more info

Comment: mxmissile , thanks for helping me . only thing I am missing is the "common Method" to get  hidden1 , hidden2 ..... (n)                                                      ####  var master = (MyMasterPage) Page.Master;
master.Hidden1Value = "something";                                                         master.Hidden2Value = "somethingfromhidden";                            
             ### Looking for some common method to find what are the hiddenfields are got called .could you please help ?

Comment: @Joe just match your property names to your hidden field IDs.

Comment: Sure , that is working as expected . But now I have to move all these logic under App_Code folder >> CommonMethods.cs , How I can access there ? so I am looking for a method which will take care about all the hiddenfields getting populated with value - hope you understood "my problem" thanks

Comment: mxmissile , need help .. I need to associate few of the web controls with CommonMethods.SomeMethod((MyMasterPage) Master).HiddenFields; ,, eg txtAccess.Text =CommonMethods.SomeMethod((MyMasterPage) .HiddenfieldValue ..  But it is not getting any value .. I need to associate the methos to some variable , please help